# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.jdbc when create jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, exception, jdbc

I created an application on Eclipse that is connected to a sqlite database that is located in the folder project. I'm using the xerial sqlite-jdbc driver and swing for objects. When I run my application on Eclipse it works fine, but when I export the application to a single jar file it shows me the error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.jdbc

I tried adding the sqlite-jdbc jar file to the classpath (I'm sure that I pressed ENTER in the manifest), running this example from xerial:

> java -classpath ".;sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar"

But it always show the error. I read and downloaded an example from here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/815186/Java-JDBC-SQLite-Read-Data-from-User-selected-db-T?msg=4911364#xx4911364xx

It's made in NetBeans and when I create the jar file for that project it doesn't have the same problem, I noticed that the jar "sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" it's included when I create the jar file for the project, but when I create the jar file for my project it doesn't include that file.

Using winrar I copied the "sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" file to the jar file of my project but it always shows the same error.(You'll think that I'm crazy trying this, but I had try a lot of things)

I had read all the question and answers on this web and other webs that presents similar or the same error, but nothing happen.

If some one knows what can I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using eclipse, you may want to try [Runnable JAR File Exporter](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-runnable-jar.htm)

[image: eclipse runnable jar]

Comment: That was the solution.